# Unpermitted parameter: :recipe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-redux

I am having an issue with submitting my data from form on the front end. Everytime I submit the form I get a **Unpermitted parameter: :recipe**

[image]

I was told to make sure my attributes on my frontend matched what was on the backend strong params.

Here is what is in my controller for my create action and my strong params

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

def create
        recipe = Recipe.create(recipe_params)
        if recipe.save
            render json: recipe
        else
            render json: { error: "Couldn't save" }
        end
    end


 private
    
    def recipe_params
        params.permit(:category_id,:name,:ingredients,:chef_name,:origin,category_attribute:[:category])
    end

end
```

And here is my React frontend where I am inputting the info in the form
**Side note I took out the event handlers for this code snippet but left the submit handler just to keep this explanation shorter**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import  Categories  from './Categories.js'



class RecipeInput extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            category: [],
            categoryId: '',
            name:'',
            ingredients: '',
            chef_name: '',
            origin: ''
        }
        this.handleNameChange.bind(this)
        this.handleOriginChange.bind(this)
        this.handleChefChange.bind(this)
        this.handleIngChange.bind(this)


        
    }

    

    componentDidMount(){
        let initialCats = [];
        const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:10524`
        const CATEGOREIS_URL =`${BASE_URL}/categories`
        fetch(CATEGOREIS_URL)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            
            initialCats = data.map((category) => {
                return category
            })
            console.log(initialCats)
                this.setState({
                    category: initialCats,
                })   
            });
    }

    
    handleSubmit = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.postRecipes(this.state)
        this.setState({
        categoryId: '',    
        name:'',
        ingredients: '',
        chef_name: '',
        origin: ''
     })
    }

    
        

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <Categories category={this.state.category}/>
                    <div>
                    <label for='name'>Recipe Name:</label>
                    <input type='text' value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleNameChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label for='name'>Country Origin:</label>
                    <input type='text' value={this.state.origin} onChange={this.handleOriginChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label for='name'>Chef Name:</label>
                    <input type='text' value={this.state.chef_name} onChange={this.handleChefChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label for='name'>Ingredients:</label>
                    <textarea value={this.state.ingredients} onChange={this.handleIngChange} />
                    </div>
                    <input value='submit' type='submit'/>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }


}

export default RecipeInput
```

I am just a little clueless on where to go to from here. Am I matching the attributes correctly?

**Edit**
I forgot to include my postRecipes function with my dispatches in place

```
export const postRecipes = (recipe)=>{
    const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:10524`
    const RECIPES_URL =`${BASE_URL}/recipes`

    
    const config = {
        method: "POST",
        body:JSON.stringify(recipe),
        headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json"
     }
    }
    //category field
    return(dispatch)=>{
    fetch(RECIPES_URL,config)
    .then(response => 
    response.json())
    .then(resp => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'Add_Recipe',
            payload:{
                category:resp.category,
                name: resp.name,
                ingredients: resp.ingredients,
                chef_name: resp.chef_name,
                origin: resp.origin,
                categoryId: resp.categoryId 
            }
        })
    })
    //.then(response => <Recipe />)
      .catch((error) => console.log.error(error))

    }
    
    
}
```

**Edit**

Here is my reducer that defines my Add-Recipe action for payload.

```
export default function manageRecipes(state={
    recipes:[],
    category:[],
}, action){


    switch(action.type){
        case 'Add_Recipe':
            const recipe = {
                name: action.name,
                ingredients: action.ingredients,
                chef_name: action.chef_name,
                origin: action.origin,
                categoryId: action.categoryId,
                category: action.category,
                // id: cuidFn()
            }

            return{
                ...state,
                recipes: [...state.recipes, recipe],
            }
        case 'Delete_Recipe':
            const recipes = state.recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.id !== action.id)
            return {...state, recipes}
        
        case 'Add_Catagory':
            const cat = {
                name: action.name
            }    
            return{
                ...state,
                category: [...state.category, cat],
            }
        default:
            return state
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `params.permit` does not list that parameter, ergo it is not allowed. You should double-check your input format and allow the parameters you want.

Comment: Your issue doesn't seem to be in the backend. In the message with the error it shows that your rails application only receives something like this `{"recipe": {}}` from your react app. Can you check the actual payload you are sending to see how that looks?

Comment: @DanielSindrestean sorry for getting back so late, I just got home. I'll update the question with my reducer.

Comment: @Stitch That's not what I meant. The issue seems to be difference between what data you are supposed to be sending from the frontend and what you are receiving in the backend. For example try logging the `config` object before sending it.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your backend

```
def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(
    :category_id, :name,:ingredients, :chef_name,
    :origin,category_attribute:[:category]
  )
end
```

Comment: So I tried this before and tried it again in case I made a change somewhere before and I get ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: recipe)

Comment: that's because the parameters you send from frontend don't look the same as the backend, try this one in your frontend:
{
  recipe: {
    category_id: 1,
    name: 'your name',
    .....
  }
}